# Variadic data structure template instantiation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The following web page has an example of a variadic data structure (a tuple) [link](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/).  I have a question on the following code, which is claimed to generate the following class hierarchy.  My question is, how is the hierarchy generated? I don't see where the new `struct type<Ts...>` is generated?  Thanks

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> {
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

  T tail;
};
```

Class Hierarchy:

```
tuple<double, uint64_t, const char*> t1(12.2, 42, "big");
```

```
struct tuple<double, uint64_t, const char*> : tuple<uint64_t, const char*> {
  double tail;
}

struct tuple<uint64_t, const char*> : tuple<const char*> {
  uint64_t tail;
}

struct tuple<const char*> : tuple {
  const char* tail;
}

struct tuple {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two class templates here

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {}; #1
```

and

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> { ... } #2
```

And what happens in this case is that #2 is considered more specialized so when you have

```
tuple<double, uint64_t, const char*>
```

#2 gets stamped out giving you

```
struct tuple<double, uint64_t, const char*> : tuple<uint64_t, const char*>
```

This keeps happening creating the chain that you have, until you get to

```
struct tuple<const char*> : tuple {
  const char* tail;
}
```

and here `: tuple` has no parameters so the only template it can call is #1 which then generates the end case of

```
struct tuple {};
```

Comment: In your second to last comment, do you mean `tuple<>`?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it is impossible to extract a single type out of the type list (that means that this list is empty), the following code takes effect:

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};
```

That is an empty struct that becomes the base for the rest of the classes.

If there is at least one type, the compiler divides the list into `class T` and the rest (one type less in the list):

```
template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> {
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

  T tail;
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this generates the next `struct tuple<Ts...>`

Comment: When a template specialization is used and isn't already explicitly defined, the compiler generates it. That's how *all* templates work. Each specialization of `tuple<T, Ts...>` "uses" `tuple<Ts...>` by subclassing. Therefore using any `tuple` specialization creates that class if necessary and also all of its superclasses.

Comment: If compiler sees that the list can be divided (`sizeof...(Ts) > 0`), it divides the list into a single type (`T`) and the rest, and applies the second rule. Sooner or later the `sizeof...(Ts)` would become 0. The compiler would apply the first rule.

Comment: Having the derived class of `tuple<Ts...>` is enough for the compiler to generate `struct tuple<T, Tz...>?

Comment: That is enough to generate the class that is a derived from derived from derived from ... derived from the base, where base is an empty struct. As long as the members are public, you shouldn't feel the difference.